# Why are RemoteAudioTracks not publishing properly?

Tags: reactjs, agora

So far, I have tested localAudioTrack. When I have play set to true, it does work. I've been trying to test out remoteAudioTracks, but had no luck. I've had this error pop up when another user joins: [publish error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxyOp.png).

I've checked out remoteUsers, and that does get populated with the other user in an array, so the other user is definitely connecting, but can't seem to get their tracks into remoteAudioTracks. It prints out an empty array.

Here is my code (Have just removed token to not expose:

```
import OverlayTrigger from "react-bootstrap/OverlayTrigger";
import Tooltip from "react-bootstrap/Tooltip";
import React, {createContext, useContext, useEffect, useRef, useState} from "react";
import {SocketContext} from "../../context/friends-socket-context.js";
import {AuthContext} from "../../context/auth-context.js";
import {GroupContext} from "../../context/group-context.js";
import axios from "axios";
import {
    useJoin, useRTCClient, useClientEvent, useIsConnected, useRemoteAudioTracks,
    useRemoteUsers,
    useRemoteVideoTracks, LocalAudioTrack, RemoteAudioTrack, useLocalMicrophoneTrack, usePublish,
} from "agora-rtc-react";
import {Room} from "./Room.jsx";
import {RenderRemoteUsers} from "./RemoteUsers.jsx";

const VoiceChannel = ({channelName, channels, addUser}) => {
    const [joined, setJoined] = useState(false)
    const [localTrackReady, setLocalTrackReady] = useState(false)
    const isConnected = useIsConnected();
    useEffect(()=> {
        console.log('isConnected', isConnected)
    }, [isConnected, joined])
    const { chatsSocketApi } = useContext(SocketContext)
    const auth = useContext(AuthContext)
    const groupControl = useContext(GroupContext)

    const [micOn, setMic] = useState(true);
    const [cameraOn, setCamera] = useState(false);

    const remoteUsers = useRemoteUsers();
    // const { videoTracks } = useRemoteVideoTracks(remoteUsers);
    const { audioTracks : remoteAudioTracks } = useRemoteAudioTracks(remoteUsers);
    useEffect(() =>{
        console.log('rAT', remoteAudioTracks)
        console.log('remoteUsers', remoteUsers)
    }, [remoteAudioTracks, remoteUsers])
    remoteAudioTracks.map(track => track.play());

    const client = useRTCClient();
    useClientEvent(client, "user-joined", (user) => {
        console.log("user joined", user.uid)
        setLocalTrackReady(true)
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        // console.log('24configuid', config.uid)
        chatsSocketApi.joinCallListener((member, channelName) => {
            console.log(member, "joining call")
            addUser(channelName, member)
        })
    }, []);

    const getAgoraToken = async () => {
        const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/getAgoraToken/' + auth.email + '/' + channelName);
        const token = res.data.token;
        console.log("Token: " + token)
        return token;
    }
    useJoin(
        {
            appid: "056e7ee25ec24b4586f17ec177e121d1",
            channel: "general",
            token: "",
        },
        joined
    );
    const joinVoiceChannel = async () => {
        setJoined(true)
        chatsSocketApi.joinCall({
            email: auth.email,
            firstName: auth.firstName,
            lastName: auth.lastName,
            pfp: auth.pfpURL
        }, groupControl.selectedGroup, channelName)
    }

    const { localMicrophoneTrack: localAudioTrack } = useLocalMicrophoneTrack(micOn);
    console.log('localTrack', localAudioTrack)
    usePublish([localAudioTrack], localTrackReady, client)

    return (
        <>
            <div className="channel" onClick={joinVoiceChannel}>
                <h1>#</h1>
                <h6>{channelName}</h6>
                <OverlayTrigger
                    placement="top"
                    delay={{ show: 250, hide: 400 }}
                    overlay={
                        <Tooltip className="tooltip">Edit Channel</Tooltip>
                    }
                >
                    <button>*</button>
                </OverlayTrigger>
                {/* <button>*</button> */}

            </div>
            <div style={{paddingLeft: "30px", marginTop: '-5px', paddingBottom: "5px"}}>
                {channels.get(channelName)?.map(member => (
                    <div style={{display: "flex", alignItems: "center", alignContent: "center", paddingTop: "15px"}}>
                        <img src={member.pfp} style={{width: '20px', paddingRight: "10px"}}/>
                        <div style={{textAlign: "center", fontSize: "14px"}}>{member.firstName+' '+member.lastName}</div>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
            {/*{joined ? <Room*/}
            {/*    cameraOn={cameraOn}*/}
            {/*    micOn={micOn}*/}
            {/*    renderRemoteUsers={() => <RenderRemoteUsers audioTracks={remoteAudioTracks} />}*/}
            {/*/>: null}*/}
            {joined ?
                <>
                    <LocalAudioTrack
                        track={localAudioTrack}
                        muted={false}
                        play={false}
                    />
                    {remoteAudioTracks?.map(track => (
                        <RemoteAudioTrack key={track.getUserId()} play={true} track={track} />
                    ))}
                </>
            : null}
        </>
    )
}


export default VoiceChannel
```